# Are normal coordinates the same as Cartesian coordinates in flat space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\gamma_v$ be the unique maximal geodesic with initial conditions $\gamma_v(0)=p$ and $\gamma_v'(0)=v$ then the exponential map is defined by
$$\exp_p(v)=\gamma_v(1)$$

If we pick any orthonormal basis, $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of  $T_pM$ then the $x_i$’s, with $x_i = \operatorname{pr}_i \circ \exp^{-1}$ and $\operatorname{pr}_i$  the projection
onto $Re_i$ , are called normal coordinates at $p$.

My question is , if our manifold $M$ is flat than does this normal  coordinates coincide  to what we call Cartesian coordinates ?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com. I suggest you migrate it to there.

Comment: Or try to answer this yourself using the fact that you know exactly what the geodesics are for a flat manifold.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described are indeed Cartesian coordinates on a flat space form.

However, this is not the usual definition of [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), which instead take the exponential of a vector without decomposing it in terms of an orthonormal basis. On a flat space form (i.e. Euclidean space), the standard definition of normal coordinates actually correspond to spherical coordinates.